# factorization of numbers with euclidian approach

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

Anyone know about this topic?. Factorization of numbers with euclidian approach
I searching in the internet, but i couldnt find any source of this topic?. Some one can help me about this topic?. I suppose to find application factorization of numbers with euclidian approach.

anyone can help?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you mean to use the [**Euclidean Algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) for *prime factorization* of a number? You may also be interested in the section on [Euclidean Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Euclidean_division).

Assuming you are interested in the unique *prime factorization* of a given number, you might also want to scroll down the page of the entry for the [**Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), where [***Euclid's Lemma***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) is used in the proof.

Perhaps you can include a specific example (problem) which you are asked to factor?

Comment: i guess so, can u give me some example of Euclidean Algorithm for prime factorization of a number sir?

Comment: I suppose to find application Euclidean Algorithm for prime factorization, but first i want to learn the theory, i'm sorry to bother u sir, but can u show me, process Euclidean Algorithm if we want to get prime factorization of 616.

I still read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic

Comment: Euclid's algorithm is sometimes used as one small part of the process of factoring a number. Given an integer $n$, there are ways of generating numbers $m$ that might have a common factor with $n$; you use Euclid's algorithm to find that common factor if there is one.